# Optimizing KNN query with multiple search conditions

Tags: postgis, knn

I have two point tables in SRID 4326: Table 1. unjoined_pts & Table 2. midpts. I want to join the attributes from the unjoined_pts table to the closest midpts table based on a few conditions.  The query has yet to complete after sometime and I am not sure if I have fully optimized my code or if something is missing from my SQL query.  I have spatial indices, vacuumed, and performed an ST_DWithin to limit the search area to only those points that are a maximum of 848 m away.  The unjoined_pts table has 9,627 points and the midpts table has 1.98 million points.

```
    CREATE INDEX unjoined_pts_geom_idx ON public.unjoined_pts USING GIST (geom);
    CREATE INDEX midpts_geom_idx ON public.midpts USING GIST (geom);
    
-- functional index of points
        CREATE INDEX ON unjoined_pts USING gist(geography(geom));
        CREATE INDEX ON midpts USING gist(geography(geom));

    VACUUM ANALYZE public.midpts;
    VACUUM ANALYZE public.unjoined_pts;
    
  EXPLAIN CREATE TABLE nearest AS
        WITH knn_midpoints AS (
            SELECT  p.lic_li_no, p.orig_licli, p.descriptor, p.attribute1, p.attribute2, ...., 
                    p.attributeN, closest_midpoint.geom
            FROM public.unjoined_pts p
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL (                        
              SELECT m.geom, m.lic_li_no, m.orig_licli, m.descriptor                                        
              FROM public.midpts m                                  
              WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom::geography, m.geom::geography, 848)
                AND p.lic_li_no = m.lic_li_no                    -- varchar (length=30)
                OR  p.lic_li_no = m.orig_licli                   -- varchar (length=30)
                AND p.descriptor != m.descriptor                 -- varchar (length=50)
           ORDER BY 
                    p.geom::geography <-> m.geom::geography      -- nearest midpoint for each unjoined point 
             LIMIT 1                                             -- limit to only a single midpoint location
           ) AS closest_midpoint
        )
            SELECT * FROM knn_midpoints;
```

EXPLAIN results from a subset of the unjoined_pts, nut I used the same number of midpts.  I removed the ST_DWithin.
[image]

Comment: Most crucially, the cast to `GEOGRAPHY` is not covered by the index - you'd need a functional index `... USING GIST ( (geom::GEOGRAPHY) );`. `ST_DWithin` is just noise with a cost for the *(K)NN* search - better remove it.

Comment: After what @geozelot said, if you still have problems, can you add an `EXPLAIN` of your request? Or even better, an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` using smaller tables that you create but sampling the big ones ?

Comment: @robinloche agreed, generally, but just a warning: sampling may lead to completely different execution plans!

Comment: @geozelot I added the functional indices, but still significant process times (not completing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you need to cast geoms to geography? At a distance of 848 m, there will be absolutely minuscule differences between spherical and planar systems.

Then I will try to avoid cross-join. Simple join will do just fine I thing. Something like this should return points that satisfy spatial and other conditions. It should be pretty quick to iterate over 9k or so points. Then you can grab them and left join them to your original table with 2M points (based on id or spatially...)

```
select p.lic_li_no, p.orig_licli, p.descriptor, p.attribute1, p.attribute2,...., p.attributeN, closest_midpoint.geom
    from public.unjoined_pts p
    left join lateral (                        
        select m.geom, m.lic_li_no, m.orig_licli, m.descriptor
            from public.midpts m
            where ST_DWithin(p.geom, m.geom, 848)
             and (p.lic_li_no = m.lic_li_no or p.lic_li_no = m.orig_licli)
             and p.descriptor != m.descriptor
        order by p.geom <-> m.geom
        limit 1) closeset_midpoint on true
```

--- EDIT ---

These indexes should also help:

```
create index midpts_licli_ix on midpts (lic_li_no);
create index midpts_orig_licli_ix on midpts (orig_licli);
```

Comment: still doesn't return any results.  I have been letting it run for more than 1/2hr.

Comment: @MJM OK, what happens if you factor out non spatial conditions?

Comment: @MJM At a closer look at where condition there should be parentheses to properly group logical predicates. Please try to put parentheses around p.lic_li_no = m.lic_li_no or p.lic_li_no = m.orig_licli.

Comment: Query returned successfully in 20 min 39 secs.  9627 entries.

Comment: @MJM it is pretty slow in my opinion. I think there is still room for optimization... But if it is god enough for you...

Comment: I was looking around and saw something about improving the method for the where conditions. I will try and find the post.

Comment: if I remove the ST_DWithin the query completes in 5 seconds.

Comment: @MJM Yes, but then you have no guaranty than point lies within required distance. KNN returns closest point, but no matter how far it really is. Alternatively you can select p-geom <-> m.geom and later check if it is lower than required value...

Comment: In fact you can do something like select a.geom <-> b.geom from a, b order by 1 and postgres is smart enough to access index only once to fetch required data for calculation and sort... I read about that somewhere... I think ;)

Comment: Also something interesting to read: https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/wont-you-be-my-neighbor-quickly-finding-who-is-nearby I did not know about btree_gist extension...